fact table contain more records than apart from keys mentioned in the dim table in power bi
Eg : dim table has two column room type and category
R1    LUXURY
R2    ECONOMY
R3    ABC
FACT TABLE columns are room_id, checkindate,location
R1  22/12/2021   Banglore
R1  1/02/2023    dELHI
R4  03/01/2024   Mumbai
R5  09/04/2023   delhi
Now as you can see r4 and r5 does not exist in dim table .What I have to do with these kind of records. There are a lot of more records.This is just and example I have mentioned
No idea what to do .

This question is similar to: fact table contain more records than apart from keys mentioned in the dim table in power bi. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Hi you need to provide some more detial https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, see how to ask. Looks you need to refresh the dim, or the fact process should have flagged this as a 'unknown' value that should have been in your dim. Your etl process needs looking at. You can do some sort of look up and set them as unknown, but it is best to fix this before it gets to Power BI
